# ccxt.base.errors.InvalidOrder: binance Order would trigger immediately

Tags: python, binance, ccxt

I am using Python, Binance, and CCXT API libraries to create a BUY order on Binance. I am getting an error when executing the code below.

**ERROR: ccxt.base.errors.InvalidOrder: binance Order would trigger immediately.**

I have also added the inputs.

Why am I getting this error?

TIA

**CODE**

```
def ccxt_create_buy_order( self, symbol: str, amount: float, price: float, stop_price: float ):
    try:
        print(" ======= BUY ORDER : ccxt_create_buy_order ================================== ")
        results = {}
        params  = { 'stopPrice': stop_price , 'timeInForce':'GTC'  }
        print("inputs symbo " + symbol + " amount/quantity " + str(amount) + " price " + str(price) )
        print( params )

        output  = self.ccxt_binance.createOrder(symbol, 'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT', amount=amount, side="buy", \
                    price=price, params=params)
```

**INPUTS**

```
 ======= BUY ORDER : ccxt_create_buy_order ==================================
    symbol      BTC/USDT 
    amount/quantity 0.0015 
    price       9872.49
    params      {'stopPrice': 9773.77, 'timeInForce': 'GTC'}
```

**LOG FILE**

> ERR-3A59F2841 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ccxt/base/exchange.py", line
>   568, in fetch
>       response.raise_for_status()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in
>   raise_for_status
>       raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self) requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url:
>   https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "../trade_binance/trade_binance.py", line 660, in
>   ccxt_create_buy_order
>       price=price, params=params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ccxt/binance.py", line 1223,
>   in create_order
>       response = getattr(self, method)(self.extend(request, params))   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ccxt/base/exchange.py",
>   line 452, in inner
>       return entry(_self, **inner_kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ccxt/binance.py", line 1954,
>   in request
>       response = self.fetch2(path, api, method, params, headers, body)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ccxt/base/exchange.py",
>   line 471, in fetch2
>       return self.fetch(request['url'], request['method'], request['headers'], request['body'])   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ccxt/base/exchange.py", line
>   580, in fetch
>       self.handle_errors(http_status_code, http_status_text, url, method, headers, http_response, json_response, request_headers,
>   request_body)   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ccxt/binance.py", line 1935,
>   in handle_errors
>       self.throw_exactly_matched_exception(self.exceptions, message, self.id + ' ' + message)   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ccxt/base/exchange.py", line
>   489, in throw_exactly_matched_exception
>       raise exactstring

**ERROR: ccxt.base.errors.InvalidOrder: binance Order would trigger immediately.**

**ETA**
@Igor Kroltar

Thanks for the response. When looking up the errors, I found the following. Where can one find the `step-size rule for the symbol`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *"Order would trigger immediately."* exception is explained in Binance's API docs here: https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/#9xxx-filter-failures

> The order's stop price is not valid when compared to the last traded price.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please see what I found in the "ETA" above.

Comment: @CaseyHarrils It is documented in the CCXT Manual here: https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/wiki/Manual#precision-and-limits